# Good Grep Tools for Windows

Tags: logs

We're looking for a Windows based tool to help us grep our apache & JBoss logs.

We have access to the unix boxes & are *generally* comfortable with the grep command, but because we don't use it often enough the knowledge takes a while to come back to hand.

Also, the structure of the team is changing from experienced contractors to graduate permies - We are having continued training sessions in unix & some of the basic commands, but the team is most definitely more comfortable in a windows GUI environment.

I've found this question over on stack overflow which has proved useful:
[What are good grep tool for Windows? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87350/what-are-good-grep-tool-for-windows).

Big guns to come out of that question include [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) & [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/).

Has anybody got any other suggestions that I might be missing please?

Cheers,

Duncs

Comment: Just to clarify, Cygwin is not tool, but an emulator of Unix environment under Windows (quite heavy in terms of space), that brings Unix command line tools.

Answer (score 3):

[GNU Utils for Windows](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the answer.

It is not just `grep`. It's a full-featured set of command-line utilities, including:

```
C:\SYSTEM>ls |grep "grep\|sed"
agrep.exe
egrep.exe
fgrep.exe
grep.exe
sed.exe
```

The main advantage of having native tools is **compatibility**; at any moment, you are ready to migrate your scripts to a *nix platforms with low effort.

I'm having them in a special directory where the system `PATH` variable points to.

The only disadvantage is that the native `grep` does not support Microsoft's regular expressions syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want to grep for the fun of it, or do you have specific types of tasks you want to accomplish?

I end up using [findstr.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (built-in) for everything. Occassionally, I miss not having a better tool, but it works for me, and I bet I use it at least a dozen times a day.

Answer (score 0):

I use [BareGrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/) from [baremetalsoft.com](http://baremetalsoft.com/).

(I also use [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) a lot)

Answer (score 0):

I had once come across [GrepWin](http://code.google.com/p/grepwin/) which was enough for my requirement. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/). Besides searching it can do replacing and runs on most versions of windows like Windows 98, 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7.  There are a number of options out there.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Search function of [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/).

Answer (score 0):

We threw [Fastvue Log Grep Utility](http://www.fastvue.co/blog/free-windows-grep-for-w3c-log-files) together to grep W3C text logs while retaining log headers and structure.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Scott. Why have you developed a new tool if there are other tools? What do you mean by "retaining log headers and structure"? Is in an advantage? How?